# micro-SD card slot not working on Microsoft Surface RT tablet

Tags: windows-rt, microsoft-surface, micro-sd-card

Whenever I try to put a micro-SD card into the slot on my Surface RT, the card does not show up at all. I don't even get an acknowledgement that some device was inserted (other than the usual sounds). When I look it up in Device Manager, it says that the device is not working properly. What is the problem?

Comment: What type of card (manufacturer, model i.e. SDHC/SDXC/..., class, size etc.) is it? Have you tried more than one card? Are you sure it's not a hardware issue, because I haven't faced any such problem.

Comment: @Karan It happens with all my cards, which are both SD and SDHC (the slot is not compatible with SDXC).

Comment: The Surface RT definitely *does* have a microSDXC card slot (see the Ports section of the [FAQ](http://www.microsoft.com/Surface/en-US/surface-with-windows-rt/specifications)). I'm using a 64GB Class 10 SanDisk microSDXC card myself.

Comment: @Karan Oh, it does. But if SD and SDHC cards don't work, then SDXC cards should probably not work either...

Comment: Yes, which is why it sounds to me like a hardware issue in your case.

Comment: @Karan Is there a way that I can fix it, or do I have to take it to Microsoft Store so that they can fix it, or do I have to get a whole new tablet?

Comment: If it's a hardware issue I highly doubt you can fix it. The tablet doesn't look user serviceable to me from any angle. Best thing to do would be to ask MS about it. Perhaps they can fit it or will exchange it if it's a manufacturing defect.

Comment: @Karan OK, I'll chat with a Microsoft employee about it. I'll mention this question.

Comment: Do let us know the outcome as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @Karan for your help. I contacted Microsoft Support and thay had me run the hardware troubleshooter, which fixed the problem.

Comment: So it was a software/driver issue after all? Must be a relief for you. :) (Also, @ notification works only for comments, not in answers.)

Comment: @Karan I'm a Stack Overflow user too, so I know. I just wanted you to see this answer.

Comment: Thanks, but I only saw it because your answer pushed it to the top of the Active list. Anyway, I wonder what exactly was fixed. Does anyone know where the Windows Hardware Troubleshooter logs its actions?

Comment: @Karan It just spontaneously fixed after I ran the troubleshooter. The troubleshooter, however, did not report any problems.

Comment: "Curiouser and curiouser!" cried Alice.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem. I solved mine my putting two pieces of tape on the side of the SD card opposite the contacts and reinsert the sd card. The problem seems to be the card receptacle and with the tape opposite the contacts it forces the card against the contacts inside the RT. Try pushing the card in with your finger prior to adding tape and holding it for a while and you will probably see the card show up in file manager.